# Ignoring case in SelectSingleNode Xpath not working.

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying the below sample to select a node by ignoring the case and the select single node retuns null.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<root><CHILD1>c1</CHILD1><CHILD2>c2</CHILD2></root>");
    var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("root");
    string nodeXpath = string.Format("//*[translate(@key, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '{0}']","child1");
    node = node.SelectSingleNode(nodeXpath);
    string innertext = node.InnerText;
```

Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@key` in XPath means a reference to an attribute named `key`. There is no such attribute in your XML. If you meant to match by element name then you're supposed to use `name()` or `local-name()` instead :

```
...
string xpath = "//*[translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '{0}']";
string nodeXpath = string.Format(xpath,"child1");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to Xml in little bid more readable way

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<root><CHILD1>c1</CHILD1><CHILD2>c2</CHILD2></root>");
var singleNode = 
    doc.Root
       .Elements()
       .FirstOrDefault(element => element.Name.ToString().ToLower().Equals("child1"));
```

But notice that XML support different nodes where name can be case sensitive(for example "Node" and "node") and "searching" elements in "ignore case" way can lead to problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, for your comments. The existing old code has this issue and has to be fixed with select single node for least changes. hence going with har07

Answer (score 0):

I was working through this today and I used your solution. I just wrapped it in a function and call it whenever I need to match on an element name that's under the root. Works like a charm. Thanks!

```
private string GetNodeXpathCaseInsensitive(string value)
{
    string xpath = String.Format("//*[translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '{0}']", value.ToLower());
    return xpath;
}
```